# How to parse the data given in input text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to paste the data in HTML input text fields in the following format from MS excel or same type of sheets:

```
123456  12  this
234567  3   before blank
111111  3   
222222  3   after blank
```

I copied the data from MS Excel which contain the single tab  between `12` and `this` and so on.. I have tried to implement it but didn't work for me. The above data will be pasted into a text area and it save into a another JavaScript variable into the following format:

```
<row dc= '" + arr[0] + "' al='" + arr[1] + "' msg='" + arr[2] + "' />
```

Where `arr[0]` is `123456`, and `arr[1]` is `12` and `arr[3]` is `this` and so on by appending the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str=document.getElementById("myTextarea").value
var t=str.split("\n");
for (var i=0;i<t.length;i++)
{
  var arr=t[i].split("\t");
  document.write("'<row dc= '" + arr[0] + "' al='" + arr[1] + "' msg='" + arr[2] + "' />'")
}
```

**Working Sample:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function submit_a () {
var str=document.getElementById("allocationstatus").value
//str=str.replace('\t','&#09;');
//document.getElementById("allocationstatus").value=str;
var t=str.split("\n");
var s='';
for (var i=0;i<t.length;i++)
{
  var arr=t[i].split("\t");
  s ="'<row dc= '" + arr[0] + "' al='" + arr[1] + "' msg='" + arr[2] + "' />'";
  alert(arr.length);
  for (var j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
{
  //alert(arr[j]);
}
  //document.write(s);
}
}
</script>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "80"  id = "allocationstatus" >stat&#09;do&#09;one
stat1&#09;do1&#09;one1
stat2&#09;do1&#09;one1</textarea>
<input type = "button" onclick = "submit_a();"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried with the above code , but it shows ''''''''

http://pastebin.com/fyAgjnuJ

Comment: I have posted a pastebin link, finally it shows a different one

Comment: try in your code :- `document.write( arr[0] +  arr[1] +  arr[2] )` thats because of some incomplete tags.

Comment: It shows this : 12345612this2345673before blank11111132222223after blank

Comment: Thanks for updating but that not will save it into the xml format , which i have posted it. I must pass this data into the xml format

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16207/discussion-between-anon-ymous-and-amit-pal)